# ItemTouchHelper onChildDraw() in API 28

Tags: android

I have a strange problem on Android API 28 with the `ItemTouchHelper` where it doesn't draw one of the icons on swiping. Did they change something in the new version that I'm not aware of?

[image]
*Edit icon is shown in API 27 but not on API 28.*

[image]
*Delete icon is shown on both API versions.*

The calculated position of the icons is the same on both versions.

**Log for delete icon**

```
API 27: D/Position: Left: 938 Top: 100 Right: 1001 Bottom: 163
API 28: D/Position: Left: 938 Top: 100 Right: 1001 Bottom: 163
```

**Log for edit icon**

```
API 27: D/Position: Left: 142 Top: 100 Right: 79 Bottom: 163
API 28: D/Position: Left: 142 Top: 100 Right: 79 Bottom: 163
```

**ItemTouchHelper**

```
abstract class ImageGroupTouchCallback(context: Context) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

[...] -> unimportant code removed

override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                         dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {

        [...] -> unimportant stuff

        // Calculate position of the icon
        val iconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
        val iconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
        val iconBottom = iconTop + intrinsicHeight
        val (iconLeft, iconRight) = getIconPositionHorizontal(itemView, iconMargin, dX)

        Log.d("Position", "Left: $iconLeft Top: $iconTop Right: $iconRight Bottom: $iconBottom")

        // swiping from left to right
        if (dX > 0) {
            background.setBounds(itemView.left, itemView.top, itemView.left + dX.toInt(), itemView.bottom)
            background.color = Color.parseColor("#3cca59")
            background.draw(c)

            // Draw the delete icon
            editIcon!!.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom)
            editIcon.draw(c)
        }
        // swiping from right to left
        else if (dX < 0) {
            background.setBounds(itemView.right + dX.toInt(), itemView.top, itemView.right, itemView.bottom)
            background.color = Color.parseColor("#f44336")
            background.draw(c)

            // Draw the delete icon
            deleteIcon!!.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom)
            deleteIcon.draw(c)
        }
    }

    private fun getIconPositionHorizontal(itemView: View, iconMargin: Int, dX: Float): Pair<Int, Int> {
        val iconLeft: Int
        val iconRight: Int

        // swiping from left to right
        if (dX > 0) {
            iconLeft = itemView.left + iconMargin + intrinsicWidth
            iconRight = itemView.left + iconMargin
        } else {
            iconLeft = itemView.right - iconMargin - intrinsicWidth
            iconRight = itemView.right - iconMargin
        }

        return Pair(iconLeft, iconRight)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the edit icon not there or just hidden? Check the Layout Inspector to verify this. If it is there, check elevations.

Comment: The icon and the color is drawn on a canvas so there is no view element in the Layout Inspector. Therefore elevations shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Any chance the omitted code to "calculate position of the icon and other unimportant stuff" has a bug in it? It's somewhat interesting that the `setBounds()` calls for the two icons uses the exact same set of parameters... maybe the pencil is being drawn on the right-hand side of the view? I don't know why this would be different between API 27 and 28, but hey.

Comment: @BenP. I added the omitted code. I have a function `getIconPositionHorizontal()` which considers the swiping direction. As you can see in the logs, the position is the same and should not be drawn on the right-hand side. That's what I don't get. I'm starting to think that this is a bug on Androids side.

Comment: For the edit icon, the `left` position is greater than the `right` position. I could see this reversing the icon's horizontal orientation, but I could also see Android deciding that this was illegal and not drawing the icon at all. And that definitely seems like the kind of thing that could change between api versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The left and right bounds on your edit icon are reversed.

> ```
> // swiping from left to right
> if (dX > 0) {
>     iconLeft = itemView.left + iconMargin + intrinsicWidth
>     iconRight = itemView.left + iconMargin
> }
> ```

This will return a pair of coordinates where the value for the icon's left side is greater than the value for its right side. Your delete icon, on the other hand, has its coordinates set correctly.

Replace the above code with this:

```
// swiping from left to right
if (dX > 0) {
    iconLeft = itemView.left + iconMargin
    iconRight = itemView.left + iconMargin + intrinsicWidth
}
```

---

To reproduce this problem I created an incredibly simple view class:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_bookmark_black_24dp);
        icon.setBounds(getRight(), getTop(), getLeft(), getBottom());
        icon.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

And then I just stuck one of these into a layout as the only view in my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.stackoverflow.MyView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

When I run the app, I don't see anything.

[image]

If I switch this line:

> ```
> icon.setBounds(getRight(), getTop(), getLeft(), getBottom());
> ```

to be this instead:

```
icon.setBounds(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
```

then everything works as expected, and I see my icon filling the screen.

[image]

Comment: I get it, it works now! Thank you so much. Wouldn't have found that without your help :)